# Approach for programmable power supply that provide positive and negative voltage

Tags: power-supply

I want to design power supply that output sweep from positive to negative voltage for dc motor parameter estimation. About +-12V 5A.
Are there any approach for this kind of application.
I have some concern as following.

1. I try to avoid using relay to switch because it disconnect the load.
2. I preferred single supply so I can use any SMPSU to powered its.

Comment: Would an H-bridge driver be suitable? These work by allowing the power to be connected "straight" or "reversed", and often have an extra freewheel (open) or brake (short) option. Can you also clarify what you mean by avoiding disconnecting the load?

Comment: @Aaron I've just seen you now deleted answer and, it's the right way to do things as far as I can tell. OK I answered in the interim period but, there's no need to delete your answer; just make it more of a proposal rather than a question.

Comment: @AaronLinnell  I want relationship between terminal voltage and current not PWM. Disconnect, I means open circuit. When I reverse polarity the relay contact  disconnect from the load for short period while switching.

Comment: I did not delete my answer, somebody else took the liberty of doing that. (Note the two different Aaron Linnells, however. I couldn't remember my login at work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Are there any approach for this kind of application*

A H-bridge controlled via pulse width modulation can take a supply of (say) 12 volts DC and produce an effective output ranging from +12 volts to -12 volts DC for a floating load such as a DC motor. This to me would be the simplest method.

Of course, both terminals of the DC motor would be used so, if one terminal cannot extricated from (say) ground then, a H-bridge may not be so easy.

Effectively, you're not designing a supply (more complex) but using an existing power supply and adding control functionality to its output.

---

Using a H-bridge with PWM to control the voltage and polarity of a load: -

[image]

Comment: Can we filter and regulate the voltage like a switching regulator? I can't imagine how it should be done.

Comment: @Mlab yes you can do both. Applying a filter to reduce PWM noise artefacts (they can cause a little overheating on DC motors) is easily achieved and, regulation of the PWM duty cycle is used to control the precise equivalent DC voltage to the motor.

Comment: If I really want to make it like switching power supply, do you have any suggestion?  If open loop push-pull PWM is equivalent to voltage, why we don't use it?  Is there any way to use analog IC to control its? should be mich faster response than microcontroller.

Comment: @Mlab sure you can. The battery I showed in my added picture can vary quite a bit in value and, you can adjust the PWM duty cycle to keep the output regulated just like you would with a buck converter. I'm sure there will be suitable controller chips if you want them.